# How to check if the multi-value field contains the value of the other field in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I need to set the field value according to the existence of another event field (e.g. a field) in a multivalued field of the same event (e.g. mv_field)

Here is an example query, which doesn't work as I expected, because the ext_field always has the value "value_if_true"

```
| ...
| eval ext_field = if(in(mv_field, field), "value_if_true", "value_if_false")
| ...
```

Could You please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found an answer on my own, believe it will help somebody;)

```
| ...
| eval ext_field = if(isnull(mvfind(mv_field, field)), "value_if_false", "value_if_true")
| ...
```

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. Reading the Splunk docs, the `mvfind` function uses a regex match, yielding the following undesirable behavior:

```| makeresults
| eval my_multival="one,two,three"
| makemv delim="," my_multival
| eval value_to_compare="re"
| eval is_present=if(isnull(mvfind(my_multival, value_to_compare)), "no", "yes")
```

Here, "yes" will be printed because "re" is a substring of "three". Instead, if you had used "^re$", then you will correctly get "no". So if you had "^three$", then you get "yes".